# Extracting value of each pixel of a tiff file

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, pixel

I have a aggregated tif file, and I want to extract the value of each pixel in the tif file. Here is my code to read values of each pixel, but all the values I got were `nan`. I do not know why.

```
import rasterio
band_id = 1  

raster = rasterio.open('MODIS_stats_output/Alb_BSA_VIS/mean_Alb_BSA_Vis_2000_183.tif',masked=True)
band_arr = raster.read(band_id)  # band_arr is a numpy array of shape (raster.width, raster.height)

px_vals = []

for x in range(band_arr.shape[0]):
    for y in range(band_arr.shape[1]):
        px_vals.append({'x': x, 'y': y, 'value': band_arr[x, y]})
```

Comment: Are you sure all the values aren't actually nan?

Comment: yes, because when I calculated the mean, it has the results which was not nan @Jon

Comment: Why the `masked=True` parameter? I cannot find documentation on it. Could you provide a sample file?